# SceneKit - Max 8 lights limit per scene, docs say per node

Tags: scenekit

I have more than 8 lights in my scene (13, but I need more).

About 2-3 per SCNNode with categoryBitMask for each group of 3, so no more than 3 are illuminating a specific SCNNode.

I have even added the lights as children of the illuminated SCNNode so they’re not all in the same parent SCNNode.

Yet only 8 lights are enabled globally by SceneKit at a time. Docs say the limit is per node though:

> SceneKit only uses up to eight light sources per node when rendering, ignoring any additional lights.

Any way around this? I was going for some much needed lights fine tuning which is now impossible

Comment: I understand it the way, that a SCNNode or multiple SCNNodes are being lit by a maximum number of 8 SCNLight at the same time.

Comment: @ZAY yeah, that’s how I understand it too. In practice it appears that’s true regardless of categoryBitMask which I am expecting to decrease that count - but it doesn’t.

Comment: I think, regardless of the Bitmask configuration, after more than 8 Light-Sources Scenekit ignores all additional Lights. It seems to be a restriction of SceneKit.